# How is the <script> tag handled at the machine level?

Tags: html, http, scripting, webserver, src

I assume the browser contacts the web server and asks for the "src" (in those situations where there's something to src).

Can that interaction be controlled in any way? 
How much information is available to the server about who wants the src and when?

Alternatively, could one deliberately 404 the request, then control the 404 mechanism to respond appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess around with 404 handling for this. If you want to dynamically generate javascript there's no need.

The browser doesn't care what URL is in the `src=""` attribute - it certainly doesn't have to end in `.js`. The important thing is that whatever the URL is, it should return its content with the content-type `application/javascript`.

So the simplest thing to do is put the path to a PHP (if that's what you're using) file and just ensure that what's returned is valid Javascript, sent with a correct `Content-Type` HTTP header

Answer (score 0):

Scripts specified via a `src` attribute are handled just like any other resource on a page. If you return a `404` code, the browser won't bother trying to deal with the server further for that resource. The server gets all of the usual HTTP request information (assuming the browser sends it normally), and the `Referrer:` header is set to the page which is including the resource.

Comment: Some web servers permit custom 404 handlers. That's what I'm on about in the final paragraph.

Comment: Sure, why not store your entire web site in a 404 handler?

Comment: @Amber: "... by taking advantage of PHP’s header() function, you can output, say, a 200 OK header rather than a 404 File Not Found header, so from the end user’s point of view, they have no idea the page wasn’t really found." -- http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/4

Comment: What would you be trying to achieve there? If you're just trying to deliver dynamically generated javascript then say that, because that's possible without doing crazy stuff with missing files

Comment: @Gareth: yes DGJ is kinda what I had in mind. I'd still like to know how the webserver does it all the same.